# My Fedora desktop keeps freezing some windows

Tags: google-chrome, fedora, freeze, microsoft-teams

My desktop keeps freezing but not everything is frozen.  Web browsers (Firefox and Chrome) freeze to where links aren't clickable and I can't even change tabs.  I'm not even able to type in text fields like the one I'm typing in now.  Things like Terminal function just fine.  I am able to switch tabs and run commands.  There are times when the mouse will move but clicking doesn't work on anything but that is much less frequent.

I do know that Chrome plays a big part in it, as does Teams.  Are there some settings I can change to make this work better?  Do I need to change some of my hardware?

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.16.16-200.fc35.x86_64 x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc
    v: 2.37-10.fc35 Desktop: GNOME 41.4 Distro: Fedora release 35 (Thirty Five)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: ASRock model: B450M Pro4 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends v: P4.60 date: 11/03/2020
CPU:
  Info: 8-core model: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen 2
    rev: 0 cache: L1: 512 KiB L2: 4 MiB L3: 32 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2260 high: 3451 min/max: 2200/4426 boost: enabled
    cores: 1: 2057 2: 3451 3: 2149 4: 2156 5: 2198 6: 2199 7: 2199 8: 2200
    9: 2190 10: 2262 11: 2113 12: 2191 13: 2199 14: 2200 15: 2200 16: 2199
    bogomips: 115197
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GK208B [GeForce GT 710] vendor: ASUSTeK GT710-4H-SL-2GD5
    driver: nvidia v: 470.103.01 bus-ID: 03:00.0
  Device-2: Logitech Webcam C930e type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 3-1:2
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.20.14 driver: X: loaded: nvidia
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa gpu: nvidia resolution:
    1: 1920x1080~60Hz 2: 1920x1080~60Hz 3: 1920x1080~60Hz 4: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GT 710/PCIe/SSE2
    v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 470.103.01 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GK208 HDMI/DP Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 03:00.1
  Device-2: AMD Starship/Matisse HD Audio vendor: ASRock
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 07:00.4
  Device-3: Plantronics Plantronics Blackwire 325.1 type: USB
    driver: plantronics,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus-ID: 1-2:2
  Device-4: Logitech Webcam C930e type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 3-1:2
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.16.16-200.fc35.x86_64 running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: ASRock driver: r8169 v: kernel port: e000 bus-ID: 04:00.0
  IF: enp4s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: mpqemubr0 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-2: virbr0 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 4.09 TiB used: 1.08 TiB (26.3%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WDBNCE5000PNC
    size: 465.76 GiB
  ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Seagate model: ST4000DM004-2CV104 size: 3.64 TiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 456.17 GiB used: 89.71 GiB (19.7%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/sda4
  ID-2: /boot size: 975.9 MiB used: 241.3 MiB (24.7%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/sda2
  ID-3: /boot/efi size: 598.8 MiB used: 13.8 MiB (2.3%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/sda1
  ID-4: /home size: 3.64 TiB used: 248.55 GiB (6.7%) fs: btrfs
    dev: /dev/sdb1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 8 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) dev: /dev/sda3
  ID-2: swap-2 type: zram size: 8 GiB used: 49.9 MiB (0.6%) dev: /dev/zram0
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 38.5 C mobo: 37.0 C gpu: nvidia temp: 53 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): fan-1: 0 fan-2: 2023 fan-3: 0 fan-4: 0 fan-5: 0
  Power: 12v: N/A 5v: N/A 3.3v: 3.39 vbat: 3.26
Info:
  Processes: 502 Uptime: 8d 4h 10m Memory: 31.26 GiB used: 9.06 GiB (29.0%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.2.1 Packages: 15
  note: see --pkg Shell: Bash v: 5.1.8 inxi: 3.3.13
```

[image]

Comment: dmesg will print out if there is an actual kernel error or crash during execution of the programs. Maybe there is not enough RAM on your device (I don't see it in the statistics above)? Fedora 35 default Firefox browser works well even on my humble Surface laptop though.

Comment: There's 32GB of RAM and 9.06 is used (Under Info).  I mainly use Chrome since it stays synced with my Google data.  No errors in dmesg since I've come out of hibernate but the problem has occurred multiple times since then.

Comment: I'm wondering if an enable/disable change of `chrome://flags/#ignore-gpu-blocklist` might fix/break things.